# Why is CMYK more suitable than RGB for printing?

Tags: model, color

We know that RGB is additive color model and CMYK is subtractive color model. RGB starts with darkness (black) and we gradually add light; an CMY(K) image requires to be illuminated by white light.

When a printer performs printing operation, how do CMYK and RGB work together to print on white paper?  And why does CMYK technology need both, white paper and white color?

N. B. - I want to understand the intuition rather than details. Please don't use too much technical term.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about software engineering

Comment: @mmathis where should I  ask?

Comment: @AlokMaity: sounds like a good question for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ but before you ask, make sure it was not already asked and answered there. Currently, I found 187 questions on that site for the keywords RGB and CMYK, you may filter them further and check them first.

Comment: The difference is in how the primary colors mix to create other colors. The additive color system creates color by mixing light. All colors and hues (including black and white) can be created by mixing red, green, and blue light (hence the name RGB). The subtractive color system creates colors by mixing paint pigments. Many hues can be created by mixing cyan, magenta, and yellow pigments - but not black or white. So you need a separate black paint (the K in CMYK). White is achieved by printing on white paper, so the lack of paint will be white.

Comment: @JacquesB please insert your comments in answer, your comments like answer and deserve upvote.

Comment: TLDR: Ink works by _subtracting_ colors from white light shining on white paper. If you subtract the red wavelengths from white light, you are left with cyan. If you subtract the green, you are left with magenta, and if you subtract the blue, you are left with yellow. Black ink is an optimization: When you want to absorb _all_ of the light, black ink does a slightly better job than if you layered cyan on top of magenta on top of yellow. Also, the black ink costs less than the colored inks.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: Mixing cyan/magenta/yellow ink will not create black, it will create a brownish color. Adding more layers of ink (when the paper is covered) will not make the color darker, it will just waste ink. Black ink is a necessity for creating darker tones.

Comment: reading @JacquesB and SolomonSlow comments, I see some further answers. I’ll vote to reopen the question. I was too often disappointed when printing wonderful RGB photos and get an average paper print: this problem needs to be seriously understood;-)

Comment: @JacquesB suppose incoming light that enters the into any red object then except red everything get absorbed. Then this red light which I see is refraction or reflection light? I seem it's refraction? What is right?

Comment: Red paint will reflect red light and refract or absorb the other colors.

Comment: @JacquesB but when red light  entered into object which is bounce inside object which we called diffuse reflection?

Comment: @JacquesB, Maybe I understated the case when I said that black ink does a "slightly better job" of absorbing light than C+M+Y. If we're measuring reflected light, then C+M+Y does absorb most of it. But, the human eye is sensitive. If we're talking about faithful color reproduction, then yes, a print made with C+M+Y alone would look "washed out" as compared with a print made with all four colors.

Comment: This question _might_ be suitable for [photography.se], if you're concerned with printing photographic images.  You'll want to tag with `printing` and `color-spaces`, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working on image editing or graphic software,  you probably wonder why you'd need to provide some more thoughts about color models:

- Colors you see on a screen are sent from a light source. No light is black. Adding light to the source is the simplest way to change the color.
- Colors you see on a paper are reflected from the ink. No ink reflects the paper color (usually white). But in reality the ink does not reflect a certain color: [It absorbs a color](https://colortutorial.design/cmyk.html) and reflect more or less the other ones.  The absorption corresponds to a subtractive effect, i.e. you add on paper ink that would subtract some light from the reflection.
  ( *If the paper is not white,  it already absorbs some colors of the white light spectrum.  So it subtracts already something and substracting, say yellow,  would then subtract even more, leading to a different color.* )

This is why RGB color model is popular for screens and light and [CMYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) for printing. (Fortunately, device drivers are making the conversion for us: most of the time we do not really need to know about such [differences](https://www.boingographics.com/blog/why-do-i-need-to-know-the-difference-between-rgb-and-cmyk)).

Comment: Plus for that it is a real technical, physical phenomena of additive/subtractive color. And monitors are mainly RGB pixels whereas printers use CMYK ink.

Comment: @Christophe "If the paper is not white, it already absorbs some colors of the white light spectrum. So it subtracts already something and substracting, say yellow, would then subtract even more, leading to a different color. "--- in CMYK we need C, M, Y, K ink to subtract R,G,B from white light. My question is ""yellow is subtracting""-- don't understand? Please give one example where yellow is subtracting on without white paper and produce unexpected color?

Comment: @Christophe when white light incident on cyan ink it absorbs red light and reflects green and blue—remember then green + blue light = cyan. My question is it only reflects green and blue light among 7 colors (white light) ? Remaining lights is absorbed like red color?

Comment: @AlokMaity Yes. I suggest to read the link behind "It absorbs color".  The principle is that the white light is made of all the colors.  When the white light hits the paper, nothing is absorbed and all the colors bounce back to your eye: you see white. When you have color yellow, the ink absorbs all the other colors but yellow and this is why you see only yellow.  The colors that you see is the color that is not absorbed.  At the other extreme:  if you ink your paper with all possible colors,  then the white light is completely absorbed, and you see nothing:  the sheet appears black.

Comment: @Christophe "it subtracts already something and substracting, say yellow, would then subtract even more"--- from this statement I understand that if paper is yellow then when white light incident on yellow paper we only see yellow color paper. If we want a printed surface to appear cyan then it absorbs red light and reflects green and blue—remember than green + blue light = cyan. Then cyan + yellow= green. We don't get cyan color on paper instead we get green color which isn't not expected. Am I correct?

Comment: @Christophe But don't understand  this sentence ""would then subtract even more""".what do mean by this sentence? After subtracting yellow, how another color will get subtracted?